# Necessary and sufficient condition for a stable fixed point (related to eigenvalues)

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

I am reading a lecture note and it says:

Suppose we have $$\dot{x} = Ax$$ and suppose $\tilde{x}$ is a fixed point. Then we have the following theorem:

> $\tilde{x}$ is stable if and only if all eigenvalues of $A$ satisfy $\text{Re}(\lambda)\leq 0$ and whenever $\text{Re}(\lambda) = 0$ we have $\dim(\mathcal{N}(\lambda I-A)) = 1$.

I am confused of the second condition. $\dim(\mathcal{N}(\lambda I-A)) = 1$ just implies that

1. the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$ is of dimension $1$.
2. it can happen that the geometric multiplicity $\leq$ algebraic multiplicity.  (if there is repeated roots of $\lambda$ )

If $\text{Re}(\lambda) = 0$, trajectory of $x(t)$ is an orbit (unstable in linear system and possibly stable in nonlinear system, for example a stable limit cycle.)

I have no idea what the second condition tells related to the stability. I mean if  "$\dim(\mathcal{N}(\lambda I-A)) \geq 1$ ", what happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assume that $A$ consists of a single Jordan block $\lambda I + N$ with $N$ nilpotent. Then $\delta x(t)$ satisfies
$$\delta x(t) = e^{(\lambda I + N)t}\delta x(0) = e^{\lambda t} e^{Nt}\delta x(0),$$
where $e^{Nt}$ has entries polynomial in $t$ since $N$ is nilpotent. Suppose column $i$ of $e^{Nt}$ contains a nonzero power of $t$; choose $\delta x(0) = e_i$ and now $\|\delta x(t)\| = \|e^{Nt}\delta x(0)\|$ grows unbounded as $t\to \infty$.

Comment: Just a small question, what is $\delta$? just a small change of $x(t)$?

Comment: Yes, a perturbation $x(t) = \tilde x + \delta x(t)$